# How to write on serial port to get caller id from modem in java?

Tags: java, serial-port, serial-communication, rxtx, tapi

am working on caller id using java language. I have usb robotic modem, and this modem is connected with the telephone line. I want to get caller id from this modem when phone is ringing.

i am using RXTX library in my sample project for caller id, now am communicating with the serial ports of the system, am successfully read and write the data from the port.

When phone is ringing, java program give output: ring, but when i pass command to modem for caller id that time output is : ERROR

Below is the sample code, please help me to display caller id.

And my modem is usb robotic modem

```
package rxtx.demo;

import gnu.io.CommPort;
import gnu.io.CommPortIdentifier;
import gnu.io.SerialPort;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Command {

    SerialPort serialPort;

    public Command() {
        super();
    }

    void connect(String portName) throws Exception {
        CommPortIdentifier portIdentifier = CommPortIdentifier.getPortIdentifier(portName);
        if (portIdentifier.isCurrentlyOwned()) {
            System.out.println("Error: Port is currently in use");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Connect 1/2");
            CommPort commPort = portIdentifier.open(this.getClass().getName(), 6000);

            if (commPort instanceof SerialPort) {
                System.out.println("Connect 2/2");
                 serialPort = (SerialPort) commPort;
                System.out.println("BaudRate: " + serialPort.getBaudRate());
                System.out.println("DataBIts: " + serialPort.getDataBits());
                System.out.println("StopBits: " + serialPort.getStopBits());
                System.out.println("Parity: " + serialPort.getParity());
                System.out.println("FlowControl: " + serialPort.getFlowControlMode());
                serialPort.setSerialPortParams(4800, SerialPort.DATABITS_8, SerialPort.STOPBITS_1, SerialPort.PARITY_ODD);
                //serialPort.setFlowControlMode(SerialPort.FLOWCONTROL_RTSCTS_IN);
                System.out.println("BaudRate: " + serialPort.getBaudRate());
                System.out.println("DataBIts: " + serialPort.getDataBits());
                System.out.println("StopBits: " + serialPort.getStopBits());
                System.out.println("Parity: " + serialPort.getParity());
                System.out.println("FlowControl: " + serialPort.getFlowControlMode());
                InputStream in = serialPort.getInputStream();
                OutputStream out = serialPort.getOutputStream();

                (new Thread(new SerialReader(in))).start();
                (new Thread(new SerialWriter(out, in))).start();

                //out.write("AT&Zn?".getBytes());
                //out.flush();
            } else {
                System.out.println("Error: Only serial ports are handled by this example.");
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SerialReader implements Runnable {

        InputStream in;

        public SerialReader(InputStream in) {
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void run() {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int len = -1;
            try {
                while ((len = this.in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
                    //System.out.println("Received a signal.");
                    System.out.print(new String(buffer, 0, len));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public static class SerialWriter implements Runnable {

        OutputStream out;
        InputStream in;

        public SerialWriter(OutputStream out, InputStream in) {
            this.out = out;
            this.in = in;
        }

        public void run() {
            try {


                byte[] array = {0x1B, 0x50, 0x0D, 0x0A};
                while (true) {
                    //this.out.write("AT#CID=1".getBytes());
                    this.out.write("AT+GCI=B5".getBytes());
                    //this.out.write("AT+VCID=2".getBytes());
                    this.out.write("AT+VCID=1".getBytes());

                    this.out.write(new byte[]{0x1B, 0x50, 0x0D, 0x0A});
                    this.out.flush();
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    byte mBytesIn[] = new byte[1024];
                    //this.in.read(mBytesIn);
                    this.in.read(mBytesIn);
                    String value = new String(mBytesIn);
                    System.out.println("Response from Serial Device: " + value);
                }
            } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            (new Command()).connect("COM6");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you send AT command to initialise the modem and also AT+VCID=1 (or its equivalent) to enable the Caller ID feature.

It's also useful to confirm existence of such service with your phone company.